# Remove blue focus border on embedded goggle maps

Tags: css, google-maps

When you click an embedded Google Map, it shows a blue border.

How do I get rid of this blue focus border???

I've tryed all of the following with no success:

```
*:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}

iframe {
    outline: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}
iframe:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    
}
#gmap_canvas:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}

.mapouter:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/davidxmartins/kyw0x6zo/12/)

Comment: If you care about accessibility (which you should), you shoud *not*  remove the highlighting of focussed/selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is what I did to remove it in dev tools.  I selected the outer div container of the map and applied the border=none in the style attribute.

Sorry but it still comes back after you drag and scroll the map.

Comment: As you can see on my fiddle I already have that in CSS. It doesn't work.